# Apache storm static variable reference from bolt

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

A bolt in my storm topology has reference to a static variable in a utility class and will this static variable stays same for each tuple processed on a worker process.

Comment: why should it change?

Comment: Actually I declared it as static and had a condition to not update that static variable if it is already initialised. But in my case, this value will change depending on the tuple content. So, I thought the condition to check that it is initialised is not a good idea. Because it will hold the value based on the first tuple flown to this task and same value will be available for all the later tuple flowing in to this task. Is that correct?

Comment: Since it changes during runtime, it should not be declared as static, I would say..? But maybe you can share the code - this would help to understand. Have you tried that out?

Comment: The task thread will stay there until there is some issues with the thread and new thread gets allocated for a task. So, the static variable in my scenario is not to be used. So, changed the logic to not have static variable.

Answer (score 0):

Task is not created for each tuple. Once the task is initiated on an executor thread, tuples will flow to this task. So, the static variable will shared across tuples.

The task thread will stay there until there is some issues with the thread and new thread gets allocated for a task. So, the static variable in my scenario is not to be used. So, changed the logic to not have static variable.